# Вывод денег с аккаунта продавца Play Market в России (физлицо)

Tags: google-play

Добрый вечер! У меня есть аккаунт разработчика и приложения с которых я планирую получать доход. Я в этом новичок и поскольку информация меняется, то хотелось бы узнать как мне поступить на сегодняшний день. Я физическое лицо. 
В аккаунте продавца есть настройка платежных данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понял, необходимо быть ИП или ООО? Собственно вопрос: как вывести деньги на карту? Как это происходит на сегодняшний день? Как быть с подоходным налогом? Как поступают на моем месте простые физические лица у кого есть желание зарабатывать на продаже приложений в России? Чтобы проблем не было с законом например. Спасибо!